# Angle preserving operators

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

An operator $T ∈ L(V )$ is said to preserve angles if $T$ is invertible, and for all nonzero $u, v ∈ V$ we have
$${(T(u), T(v)) \over {∥T(u)∥∥T(v) ∥}} = {(u, v) \over {∥u∥ ∥v∥}} $$

**(a) Prove that if operators $T_1, T_2$ preserve angles, then $T_1T_2$ and $T_1^{−1}$ also preserve angles.**

To tackle this problem I am thinking to show following facts:

Suppose $ V\in \mathbb R^n $ then $T_1 \in L(V)$ and $T_2 \in L(V)$ and $T_1T_2: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow  \mathbb R^n$.

Assume there exists the positive number $\lambda > 0 $ and

(i) $T_1T_2(v) · T_1T_2(w) = λ^2(v · w)$ for all $v, w ∈ \mathbb R^n$

(ii) $ ||T_1T_2(v)|| = λ||v||$ for all $v ∈ \mathbb R^n$

Then I show $${(T_1T_2(u), T_1T_2(v)) \over {∥T_1T_2(u)∥∥T_1T_2(v) ∥}} = {(u, v) \over {∥u∥ ∥v∥}} $$

Please correct me if I am wrong. Hints and helps are greatly appreciated.

Same approach applies to $T^{-1}$.

**(b) Suppose $T$ preserves angles. Let $T = SP$ be the polar decomposition, where $S$ is
an isometry, and $P$ is a positive operator. Prove that $P$ preserves angles.**

I don't have any ideas for this one. Please direct me how to approach this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Another way to approach this is to show that the set of transformations $T$ that preserve angles (usually called *conformal transformations*) are precisely those of the form $\lambda S$, where $\lambda \neq 0$ and $S$ is orthogonal. Then, the above claims follow almost immediately from the corresponding (easy) claims for orthogonal matrices.

Comment: Thanks, how about b)? How do I start? Sorry there was a mess in b earlier.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: Also, note that your assumption (ii) follows from (i), i.e., we only need assume the first.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: For the polar decomposition problem, note that since $S$ is an isometry, it preserves angles. Then, use both results from (a).

Comment: what do you mean by use (b) and (a)? You mean the two assumptions I made in (a)? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I mean, use the results you just proved in (a) and (b).

Comment: So for b) since T preserves angles we have $${(T(u), T(v)) \over {∥T(u)∥∥T(v) ∥}} = {(u, v) \over {∥u∥ ∥v∥}}$$. Then I guess I have to show $${(P(u),P(v)) \over {∥P(u)∥∥P(v) ∥}} = {(u, v) \over {∥u∥ ∥v∥}}$$. Right? My problem is I don't really understand the concept of polar decomposition. Since $S$ is isometry, we have $||Sv|| = ||v||, and we also have $S^*S = I$. How do I use concept of isometry here. I am having a problem as I don't understand the polar decomposition. Thanks for help so far!

Comment: All that matters about $S$ is that (since it is an isometry) it preserves angles. Thus, by (b), so does $S^{-1}$.

Comment: Btw, I just reread your comment from your answer and I just noticed that you said to use the results I proved in (a) and (b). But I don't have an answer for b) yet. So how do I approach again?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I was confused by the original formatting of the question; I mean, use the two results from (a).

Comment: Thanks, Since S preserves angles, $T = SP $ => $ TS^{-1} = P $. In a, I have proved that multiplication of two operators have angles and inverse of a operator has angles. So if I could show that $TS^{-1}$ have angles then P has angles. Am I assuming right?

Comment: Yes, that's right: By (a) $S^{-1}$ preserves angles since $S$ does, and by the other part of (a) $TS^{-1}$ preserves angles because $T$ and $S^{-1}$ do.

Comment: Thanks! It helps a lot. Again thanks for your time and explanation since it's been a long conversation!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it helpful!